# Firebase push-notifications not appearing as a Pop-up message - c#

Tags: javascript, c#, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a C# site that allows the user to create a Notification for it to be sent out to our mobile App using C# and Firebase for Android phones.
The notifications appear in the System Tray but we want it to also generate a Fore ground popup message similar to that to WhatsApp etc.

Im not sure if this is set up in the APP or in the post code from the website.
At the moment the website posts to "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send".

this is what we have so far:

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);

```
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + serverKey);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                //string json = "{\"to\": \"" + regID + "\",\"notification\": {\"title\": \"New deal today\",\"body\": \"20% deal! Don't miss it\"},\"priority\":10}";

                //string json = "{\"registration_ids\": [\"" + regID + "\", \"" + regID2 + "\"],\"notification\": {\"title\": \"New deal\",\"body\": \"20% deal! 2019\"},\"priority\":10}";

                string[] deviceIds = new string[] { regID, regID2, regID3 };
                var msg2send = new
                {
                    registration_ids = deviceIds,
                    priority = 28,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        body = "THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE",
                        title = "My NEW App",
                        icon = "displayicon",
                        priority = "high",
                        show_in_foreground = "true",
                        targetscreen = "detail",
                        color = "#189fd2"
                    },
                    data = new
                    {
                        priority = "high",
                        notice = "THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE",
                        show_in_foreground = "true",
                        targetscreen = "detail",
                        color = "#189fd2"
                    }
                };


                var json = serializer.Serialize(msg2send);

                //registration_ids, array of strings -  to, single recipient
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                NotificationResultModel noteResult = serializer.Deserialize<NotificationResultModel>(result);
            }
```

Can anyone tell me if I need to add a variable in the notification section? I presumed show_in_foreground would do it with a priority of high - but alas this doesn't. 
Or does this need to be set up in the APP code?

Pluse, how does the ICON work too - if I set a full URL to an image then it works on desktop but not mobile APP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Push notification You need to implement it in the App side also. App will get FCM regeneration's key and send it server side and then server side will send message using that registration id to specific device. Then device will show the Notification.

Comment: Hi - am I using the correct values in the Notification section of the POST or am I missing something? 
How do you set it up in the APP - we are using Cordova.

Comment: device id's which are you using, where did you get it? i don't think these are valid id.

Comment: device ids are created on registration - the messages are coming through OK in the System Tray but not as a POP-UP in the Foreground.

Comment: Every app in Android device which is using FCM  have a different registration id. You need to use your app registration id.

Comment: Thats fine - the Background notifications are working - we need the Foreground notifications to popup.

Comment: Unfortunately we didnt write the App side code so we cant share it - would you be able to share any examples on what the App code should look like so we can share with the external dev team? thanks for all your help